# How to pass variables from PHP to Javascript using Ajax calls

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818870/how-to-pass-php-variable-value-to-javascript) and assumed the technique in the answer would work with ajax calls. I have my ajax and php code below but it does not work.The client does not recognize the 'passed' variable. I do not know why nor how to remedy this.

**Javascript**

```
var irrelevant = 'irrelevant';

   $('body').click(function(){


            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: {mydata: irrelevant},    
            success: function(){

            console.log('worky');

            alert(myvar); // NOT worky!

                    }

            });

    });
```

**PHP File**

```
<?php


$thing = 10;


?>


<script>

var myvar = "<?php echo $thing; ?>";

</script>
```

Comment: there is no accepted answer in the [question you mention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818870/how-to-pass-php-variable-value-to-javascript).

Comment: Sorry I was reading the comments and didn't look for the green check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this in your `ajax.success`

```
success: function(data){
   console.log('worky');
   alert(data); // It should now, worky!
}
```

and in you php

```
<?php

   echo 10;

?>
```

Comment: works great, although it would be nice to have an example or an array of variables instead of a single variable ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try this
in php

```
<?php  $thing = 10; ?>


<script>

var myvar = "<?php echo $thing; ?>";

</script>
```

javascript

```
$('body').click(function(){

            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.php',
            data: {mydata: irrelevant},    
            success: function(data){
                $("#hiddendiv").html(data);
                alert(myvar);
            }
       });  
});
```